# How To Fix While Loop Menu?

Tags: c#

I'm wanting to have it so each time you go into a menu and finish it, it goes back to the main menu where you have the option of either continueing or exiting.

Each time I actually go into a menu, I get stuck in a loop and it does not go back to the main menu, how can I fix this?

```
  static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        addFACTS();
        Console.WriteLine("Please Pick An Option By Replying Either 1 or 2:\n1. Input Your Medical Conditions & View Them At The End \n2. View Medical Conditions \n 3. Exit");
        bool exit = false;
        while (exit == false)
        {
            bool numberLoop = false;
            while (numberLoop == false)
            {
                string StringInput = Console.ReadLine();
                int input = 0;
                if (int.TryParse(StringInput, out input))
                {
                    numberLoop = true;
                }
                switch (input)
                {
                    case 1:
                        Console.Clear();
                        userInput();
                        Console.Clear();
                        infer();
                        printFACTS();
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        Console.Clear();
                        FACTS["headache"] = true;
                        FACTS["vomiting"] = true;
                        printFACTS();
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        exit = true;
                        Environment.Exit(0);
                        break;
                }
            }
        }          
    }
```

```
        public static void printFACTS()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("----------------");
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, bool> fact in FACTS)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} = {1}", fact.Key, fact.Value);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("----------------");
            Console.WriteLine("\nPress Any Key To Terminate The Program...");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public static void infer()
        {
            do
            {
                numberOfFacts = countFACTS;
                FACTS["flu"] = FACTS["headache"] && FACTS["vomiting"];
                FACTS["prescribeAntibiotics"] = FACTS["infection"];
                FACTS["prescribePainkillers"] = FACTS["headache"];
                FACTS["gastroenteritis"] = FACTS["nausea"] && FACTS["fatigue"];
                FACTS["healthy"] = FACTS["infection"];
                FACTS["prescribePainkillers"] = FACTS["prescribePainkillers"];
            }
            while (numberOfFacts != countFACTS);
        }
```

Comment: @ShahidManzoorBhat could you show me a code example? I'm struggling to wrap my head around it

Comment: Can you post the code for `infer` and `printFACTS` methods. All seems to be okay apart from that

Comment: Is it exiting the loop after `infer` function

Comment: It exits the do while in the infer function but it doesn't exit the numberLoop

Comment: @ShahidManzoorBhat but the numberLoop turns from false to true if the input is any integer, the condition is any number, not 3

Comment: After I pick a case and it goes through the case, I want the code to restart at the main menu, asking me to pick between 1-3 depending on where I want to navigate to

Comment: Does the answer resolve your query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place the console writeline statement inside of your first while loop

```
while (!exit)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Please Pick An Option By Replying Either 1 or 2:\n1. Input Your Medical Conditions & View Them At The End \n2. View Medical Conditions \n 3. Exit");
    bool numberLoop = false;
    while (!numberLoop)
    {
       // Rest of your code
    }
}
```